# InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.

Tags: vb.net

Well, merry christmas all!

I am having trouble with the following whilst writing my chatroom program. I am adding an item to a listview, but when i try to add text to the last subitem, I get the error InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.

I have done the following:

```
msgbox(listview1.subitems.count())
```

and that returns 5, so I assume that means I have a total of 6 columns (the counting begins from 0 - 5 not 1 - 5.

What could be the problem? The rest of the code is:

```
Sub AddClient(ByVal client As connection, ByVal strings() As String)
    Dim l As New ListViewItem(strings)
    l.ImageIndex = GetFlag(strings(1).ToLower)
    l.Tag = client
    numcon1.Text += 1
    l.SubItems(5).Text = "test phrase"
    l.SubItems(4).Text = strings(7)
    addtoconsole(strings(3) & " ~ " & strings(1) & " Has Connected.")
    ListView1.Items.Add(l)
    If audiocon = "True" Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("newuser.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
    Else
    End If
    If notifcon = "True" Then
        NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "A friend is online!", strings(3) & " ~ " & strings(1), ToolTipIcon.Info)
    End If
End Sub
```

thanks so much!

Comment: index starts from 0, so you should read 0,1,2,3,4, and count is 5 not 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that returns 5, so I assume that means I have a total of 6 columns (the counting begins from 0 - 5 not 1 - 5.

No. It means 5 columns in total. Starting with index 0 and ending with index 4.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I can make such an error, I've been up for ever wrapping presents and such. Hmm, there are infact a total of 6 columns

Comment: @Jackles - Regardless. If there are indeed 6 columns, the count would be 6, not 5 and the indexing would run from 0 to 5. I suggest you debug through and look again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, perhaps it was just a malfunction as I re-created the column and it resolved the issue. Thanks a lot and have a good christmas!